# ImportError: cannot import name 'UserModel'

Tags: python, flask

HELP, I have this `appp.py` file:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, make_response
import json
from flask_restful import Api
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import models,resources

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

api.add_resource(resources.UserRegistration, '/registration')
api.add_resource(resources.UserLogin, '/login')
api.add_resource(resources.UserLogoutAccess, '/logout/access')
api.add_resource(resources.UserLogoutRefresh, '/logout/refresh')
api.add_resource(resources.TokenRefresh, '/token/refresh')
api.add_resource(resources.AllUsers, '/users')
api.add_resource(resources.SecretResource, '/secret')

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///app.db'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'waaahawhawaahhawhaw'

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

@app.before_first_request
def create_tables():
    db.create_all()

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return jsonify({'message': 'Hell to the World!'})

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug = True)
```

and here are the `models.py` file:

```
from appp import db

class UserModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(120), unique = True, nullable = False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable = False)

    def save_to_db(self):
        db.session.add(self)
        db.session.commit()

    @classmethod
    def find_by_username(cls, username):
        return cls.query.filter_by(username = username).first()
```

and the `resources.py` file

```
from flask_restful import Resource, reqparse
from models import UserModel

parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
parser.add_argument('username', help = 'This field cannot be blank', required = True)
parser.add_argument('password', help = 'This field cannot be blank', required = True)

class UserRegistration(Resource):
    def post(self):
        data = parser.parse_args()

        if UserModel.find_by_username(data['username']):
            return {'message': 'User {} already exists'. format(data['username'])}

        new_user = UserModel(
            username = data['username'],
            password = data['password']
        )
        try:
            new_user.save_to_db()
            return {
                'message': 'User {} was created'.format( data['username'])
            }
        except:
            return {'message': 'Something went wrong'}, 500
```

Once I try the run the app I get this error message:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'UserModel'

Indeed I found other question like mine and they helped me understand why I'm getting this error but none of them helped me work around it.
My guess is that python (or flask) can't load the class `UserModel` from model.py because of model.py (or the class `UserModel`) is still initializing and it needs db from appp.py which is waiting for resources.py which cannot be loaded cuz it's waiting for models.py.
How to fix this ???? btw I'm new to all this and I'm just following [this tutorial](https://codeburst.io/jwt-authorization-in-flask-c63c1acf4eeb)

Here is the project structure

```
test
|---appp.py
|---models.py
|---resources.py
```

The 3 files are next to each other in the test folder.

Thank you

Comment: can you show the project structure?

Comment: So `app` is essentially your project folder, and I'm guessing you called it `app` (you should call it the name of the project by the way). In which case you may have more luck like so `from app.models import UserModel`

Comment: Here I edited the post to show you the project structure, it's similar to what's in the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

To expand, here is an example in the the context of my comment..

```
from test.models import User, Role, UserRoles,\
Regions, RegionAttributes, CityAttributes,\
UserAttributes, SkillTracker, RegionWar,\
Articles
```

You requested that I explain the differences with importing.

I'm not sure it's something one can explain in a few words but ill try my best to not overcomplicate it.

You have your project folder called `test` and writhing this folder is your `models.py`. Because models file is within the test folder (test is a module in this case) you're importing a class, within a file, within a project directory, which ends up looking like this:

```
from test import models

--test

   |

    --models.py
```

In plain English you could say it means, from the test folder, I want to import the file models.py

Hope this adds some clarity, this would be a well googled search, I'm sure there are lots more better explanations out there and I'm probably missing something out.

The reason why one way didn't work, was because you have to import from a module, while app, models and UserModel are not modules.

Comment: is it necessary to call the project folder by the same name as app? or it's a convention/good practice.
and btw I tried this `from app.models import UserModel` but nothing it tells me that app is not a package

Comment: @Green Hey, where my project folder is called `app` yours is called `test` so replace app with test. `test.models` and let me know how that goes

Comment: hey, I renamed the file to make it also `test.py`, and did the `from test.models import UserModel` but it didn't work either now I'm getting this error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'test.models'; 'test' is not a package`

Comment: I never said change a file name. Please rename the file back to what it was originally

Comment: Done, the thing that I don't understand is why when I downloaded the project of the tutorial it worked while when I try to do the same thing step by step as described it doesn't work? and thank you for being patient with me.

Comment: I'm going to look through the tutorial you are following and perhaps even recommend the one that I got started with instead.

Comment: Thank you so much, I'll wait for your reply

Comment: I need you to retry `from test import models`

Comment: It worked ^_^, I don't understand the difference between `from test import models` and `from models import UserModel` or even `from test.models import UserModel` but it worked thank you so much.
If you can explain the difference that would be very helpful.

Comment: Sorry I got caught up that I forgot to mention it but it didn't actually work.
Indeed I'm not getting the `ImportError` anymore but if a view function or something is executed that needs the `UserModel` class I'm getting that `UserModel` is not defined.
I ended up gathering all the code in one file just so that I don't stay blocked here but I need to fix it.
Btw even the code from the tutorial has the same issue.

Comment: Do you have it uploaded to Github?

Comment: https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world is the first Flask tutorial I follwed

Answer (score 0):

You must create a separate file to write the db syntax, then import it in models

in db.py:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()
```

on main of app.py you can put this code:

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    from db import db
    db.init_app(app)
    app.run(port=5000)
```